# How you know where to use LCM (Least Common Multiple)

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm new in number theory and my question might be very simple for you, but I don't understand how you know when to use LCM.

For example in this question: Mike and Sara work together and Sara takes a break every 45 min and Mike takes a break every 20 min. After they finish their break (they are having break together), how long before they take break TOGETHER again? The answer is LCM(45,20) = 180 min.

Maybe I don't get something right, but I don't understand why we use LCM?

Can you explain?

Comment: LCM tells you how to combine two divisibility relations into one, as follows  $$  a,b\mid c\iff {\rm lcm}\,(a,b)\mid c$$

Comment: Assume that Mike's breaks last equally long, and Sara's breaks also last equally long.  If a break lasts at most $5$ mins for both parties, then the answer is as you state.  If each of Mike's breaks lasts more than $5$ mins, then the answer is $90$ mins.  Otherwise, if each of Sarah's breaks lasts more than $5$ mins, then the answer is $140$ mins.  If you notice, $5=\gcd(20,45)$.

Comment: Mike has breaks at $x=n*20$ minutes.  Sarah has breaks at $y=m*45$ minutes.  The have mutual breaks when $x=y=n*20=m*45$.  This time is a multiple of 20.  It is also a multiple of 45.  So it is a common multiple of 20 and 45.  The first such common break will be the lowest such common denominator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They take break together again whenever the time elapsed is a multiple of both $45$ and $20$. The *first* time they take break together is the smallest such common multiple – in other words their lowest common multiple.